# Using Nuxt.js programmatically, but reusing the active Nuxt instance

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, middleware

can anyone point me in the right direction for using Nuxt.js programmatically inside a serverMiddleware?

XY: I want to run `nuxt.renderRoute` from inside a serverMiddleware that defines an API endpoint using Express. I can see examples in the docs (https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/nuxt-render/), but it looks like the `loadNuxt` method would start an entirely new Nuxt.js instance, wouldn't it? I want to re-use the Nuxt instance that already exists and is running the serverMiddlewares.

So to be clear - Nuxt.js is already up and running (who else would be running the serverMiddlewares?) so I just want to re-use that active instance to manually invoke `renderRoute`, instead of starting a new Nuxt instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. If you register the Express middleware with a Nuxt.js module, you can access the nuxt instance with `this.nuxt` inside the module.

Comment: just to add some doc, https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware/ and a git ex, https://github.com/nuxt-community/express-template

Comment: @Fabis could you share how you registered the module? I did it with an inline function and the endpoints work but `this.nuxt.renderRoute is not a function`

Comment: hmm I just noticed you wrote you access the instance inside the module, but not the serverMiddleware itself. Did you manage to get it inside the serverMiddleware? or pass it from the module to the middleware?

Comment: @kurdemol94 Use this.addServerMiddleware() from within the module and pass in the `nuxt` object to the handler function